# Adding tiled map to QGIS and exporting as web map

Tags: raster, tiles, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have a set of drone imagery that was processed using Agisoft PhotoScan and converted to Map tiles.

I am now looking on how can I add the map tiles in my QGIS for exporting as a web map? I have a local server that use to store the exported web map.